# use success_url to go to root directory after submit form

Tags: django, post, django-forms, submit

I have a simple class based view (in an app `video`) that is creating an object using a form in a template (upload_video.html). When I submit the form, I just want to redirect to the home page, or the root index. It seems like this should be so easy. I am getting an error saying there is no page. I have tried several different ways of doing this, the code i have below is just one example.

**views.py**

```
class UploadVideo(CreateView):
  model = Video
  fields = ['title', 'description']
  template_name = 'upload_video.html'
  success_url = reverse_lazy('index.html')
```

**upload_video.html**

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Video"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**root.urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', index),
    url(r'^video/', include('video.urls'))
```

**Error**

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/video/index.html
Using the URLconf defined in flash2.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^$
^video/ ^upload [name='upload']
The current URL, video/index.html, didn't match any of these.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass urlname to the revers_lazy method, not the template name. Try to change in url.py:

```
url(r'^$', index, name="index")
```

And in UploadVideo class:

```
success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
```

Comment: this still does not work. The url that it is trying to go to is: _http://127.0.0.1:8000/video/index.html_, when the correct url should just be: _http://127.0.0.1:8000_

Comment: @ratrace123 probably you have url named `index` in video.urls? If so you need to change name to something else.

Comment: so I had a `success url` in my `video app` urls file that was pointing to `index.html`. But I thought that it would not matter because it would find the correct url in the root urls file first (at least thats the order it looks for urls explained in the django docs). Anyways it works now thanks for the help